# Most appropriate UI design pattern and JavaFX questions?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am attempting to come up with a "big picture" outline for a picture manipulation desktop application I would like to make, but due to my lack of extensive experience with implementing UI design patterns - I am struggling to find an appropriate one for my needs.

Most of my experience with UI design patterns was a few school projects utilizing the Model-View-Presenter (MVP) design pattern with Java Swing. Since Java Swing is on the way out, I am trying to use JavaFx for my UI needs moving forwards.

With a couple projects recently I attempted to use MVP with JavaFX with little success as I was stuck with the longest time connecting the user actions from the View (a JavaFX application) to the Model. I kept running into roadblocks where any attempt to connect an instance of the View to a Presenter (which would then give the logic for which Model methods, details here aren't important) would fail since the View would create another instance of itself (separate application thread from start()) with no reference to the Presenter or Model methods.

So in my rush to complete the project, I implemented a very ugly work basically hooking up the Model methods directly with their related View components. The projects works, but violates many fundamental design principles.

Going forward with this next project I would like to avoid making that mistake from the get go with a better overall design that can adequately deal with the issue I face (described above) while still maintaining fundamental design principles.

Any solution I think of involves having the View (the JavaFx Application) be where the program runs from, but that appears the violate the whole idea of having interchangeable Views. Is JavaFX just not meant to be flexible for what I'm looking for? Does anyone have any potential solutions to my problem here, both on the design pattern and JavaFX front?

Comment: "*Since Java Swing is on the way out*" It's not really, [support continues](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) for at least another 7 years.

Comment: Very broad and not clear. JavaFX already implements a sort of MVC pattern. Show a sample code of what you did and explain which part of it you didn't like.

Comment: @user1803551 - I would still call it "on the way out" as it has less and less support from the community...and it's incredibly hideous to look at. I rarely see a Swing application that doesn't look like a 90's era Linux project...

Comment: Perhaps the question is a bit unclear, but it is fairly easy to understand what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVP pattern in JavaFX is implemented as an FXML View connected to a controller class as the Presenter that launches separate Model threads as needed for various computations/tasks that feed into the View controls.  In JavaFX you create the FXML view with [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).  SceneBuilder creates the visual part of the GUI in a FXML file that is a passive file containing all of the visual attributes.  Then you attach a controller class that handles all of the events from the GUI controls.  This implements the Presenter aspect of MVP.  Then the Model is a separate thread running various computations in the background and interacting with the JavaFX thread as needed.  If the computations are not too intensive, you can just run them in the JavaFX thread itself.  If they take a lot of CPU cycles, you must run then in a separate thread so you don't lock up the GUI.